# Inject into python class for testing, without modifying the class

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, python-mock

I am tasked with create unit test code for our production pipeline, without modifying the production pipeline whatsoever. The pipeline has methods for writing to and reading from queues. I'm using mock to override those calls to create the single "unit" test. But am stuck with one last part.

I need access to the object created in the pipeline, but the method that creates it does not return the object. It's also not acceptable to set the object to self so that it stays in memory after the method returns.

We were wondering if theres a way to inject into the class method while it is running, so that I can retrieve the production object before the method returns.

I created a dummy example below, but the methodology is the same. Please let me know if you have questions or if I'm not explaining this well. Thanks.

```
class production(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.object_b = 'Test Object'

    def run(self):
        "Other lines of code"
        object_a = self.create_production_object()
        "Other lines of code"
        "Test object here"
        return 0




    def create_production_object(self):
        return 'Production Object'

test_prod_class = production()
test_prod_class.run()
assert(test_prod_class.object_a, 'Production Object')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about overwriting the method that creates the object so that it also stores the object in `self`?

```
class MockProduction(production):

    def create_production_object(self):
        self.object_a = super(MockProduction, self).create_production_object()
        return self.object_a
```

Comment: That doesn't really work for us, because then whenever you modify the production code, you'd have to make the same modifications to the test production code. Thanks though.

Comment: @mobone Not with inheritance and `super` (see edit).

Comment: @mobone Note that all other methods are inherited from `production`, so there is no need to change them in the child class just because they change in the parent class. And since I call the parents `create_production_object` now, even changes in that method will automatically propagate to the test class.

Comment: I was able to override our "store_production_object" method to set self. Thanks.